# PCA graph of individuals from principal rather than PCA

Tags: r

I am trying to run PCA in R, I have to do it with rotation and without rotation. Then, I need to plot the individuals graph.

Rotation is available in `psych::principal` ([documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/2.1.3/topics/principal)), but there are no functions that create an individual graph from `psych::principal` output.

On the other hand, I can create an individual plot with `FactoMineR::PCA` ([documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/FactoMineR/versions/2.4/topics/PCA)), but `FactoMineR::PCA` cannot perform rotation.

Can I have something that combines both, rotation option vs not and graph of individuals?